# Entity Framework 5 - read a record then delete it in loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I am having issues with my application. I have a db table for a print queue. When I read from that table in a loop, once I add that record to the view model, I then want to delete it from the database...this would be the most efficient way to do it, but EF barks:

> *An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.*

I've tried using multiple contexts... but that didn't seem to work either. I've seen articles like [Rick Strahl's](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Feb/05/Linq-to-SQL-DataContext-Lifetime-Management), but frankly it was above my level of understanding, and not exactly sure if it helps my issue here and seemed quite an in depth solution for something as simple as this.

Is there a simple way to accomplish what I am trying to achieve here?

Here is my code:

```
public List<InventoryContainerLabelViewModel> CreateLabelsViewModel(int intFacilityId)
        {
            var printqRep = new Repository<InventoryContainerPrintQueue>(new InventoryMgmtContext());
            var printqRepDelete = new Repository<InventoryContainerPrintQueue>(new InventoryMgmtContext());
            IQueryable<InventoryContainerPrintQueue> labels = 
                printqRep.SearchFor(x => x.FacilityId == intFacilityId);

            List<InventoryContainerLabelViewModel> labelsViewModel = new List<InventoryContainerLabelViewModel>();

            if (labels.Count() > 0)
            {
                //Get printq record
                foreach (InventoryContainerPrintQueue label in labels)
                {
                    IEnumerable<InventoryContainerDetail> icDtls = 
                        label.InventoryContainerHeader.InventoryContainerDetails;

                    //Get print details
                    foreach (InventoryContainerDetail icDtl in icDtls)
                    {
                        labelsViewModel.Add(new InventoryContainerLabelViewModel()
                            {
                                ...
                                populate view model here
                            }
                        );//Add label to view model

                    } //for each IC detail

                    //Delete the printq record
                    printqRepDelete.Delete(label); <======== Error Here

                } //foreach label loop
            }//label count > 0
            return labelsViewModel.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: *"I've tried using multiple Contexts."* For sure, the multipe context way is wrong. But in other words you also tried to inject the same context instance into your two repositories instead of creating a context (`new InventoryMgmtContext()`) twice - and this didn't work either, right?

Comment: That is correct. I created 2 instances of the repository each with new contexts and used one to read and one to delete. var printqRep = new Repository<InventoryContainerPrintQueue>(new InventoryMgmtContext());
            var printqRepDelete = new Repository<InventoryContainerPrintQueue>(new InventoryMgmtContext());

Comment: Yes, but did you also try to use only one repository and one context?

Comment: Yes, I tried that first. I also tried putting the delete statement outside of the read loop and just read through them all again, assuming that if the read was complete, the conflict would no longer be there...but same error.

Comment: While the foreach is being processed it seems that the EntityState changed for that Entity and that is being picked up by the IEntityChangeTracker. When you are trying to delete the object maybe EF prevents that because you are fetching the data in that moment and that could break the paging, etc. I've done some research but I am not sure if/why the EF changes the EntityState while you are reading/accessing an Entity, this behavior seems quite logical though, and very similar to DataReaders. You can, however, load a `List<InventoryContainerPrintQueue>` and Delete those objects outside the for

Comment: Load a `List<InventoryContainerPrintQueue>` with the objects you want to delete instead of just deleting them, and outside the `foreach` you can code other loop to delete those entities.

Comment: This didn't work either, same error. In the end, I added a column to the printq table for status, then in the the loop updated it to processed, then called a separate method to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I added a column to the printq table for status, then in the the loop updated it to processed, then called a separate method to delete it.

```
public List<InventoryContainerLabelViewModel> CreateLabelsViewModel(int intFacilityId)
    {
        InventoryMgmtContext dbContext = new InventoryMgmtContext();
        var printqRep = new Repository<InventoryContainerPrintQueue>(dbContext);

        IEnumerable<InventoryContainerPrintQueue> unprintedPrtqRecs = 
            printqRep.SearchFor(x => x.FacilityId == intFacilityId && x.Printed == false);

        List<InventoryContainerLabelViewModel> labelsViewModel = new List<InventoryContainerLabelViewModel>();

        if (unprintedPrtqRecs.Count() > 0)
        {
            //Get printq record
            foreach (InventoryContainerPrintQueue unprintedPrtqRec in unprintedPrtqRecs)
            {
                IEnumerable<InventoryContainerDetail> icDtls = 
                    unprintedPrtqRec.InventoryContainerHeader.InventoryContainerDetails;

                //Get container details to print
                foreach (InventoryContainerDetail icDtl in icDtls)
                {
                    labelsViewModel.Add(new InventoryContainerLabelViewModel()
                        {
                            ...
                        }
                    );//Get IC details and create view model
                } //for each IC detail

                unprintedPrtqRec.Printed = true;
                printqRep.Update(unprintedPrtqRec, unprintedPrtqRec, false);

            } //foreach label loop

            //Commit updated to Printed status to db
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

        }//label count > 0
        return labelsViewModel;
    }

    public ActionConfirmation<int> DeletePrintQRecs(int intFacilityId)
    {
        InventoryMgmtContext dbContext = new InventoryMgmtContext();
        var printqRep = new Repository<InventoryContainerPrintQueue>(dbContext);

        IEnumerable<InventoryContainerPrintQueue> printedPrtqRecs =
            printqRep.SearchFor(x => x.FacilityId == intFacilityId && x.Printed == true);

        foreach (InventoryContainerPrintQueue printedPrtqRec in printedPrtqRecs)
        {
            //Delete the printq record
            printqRep.Delete(printedPrtqRec, false);
        }

        //Save Changes on all deletes
        ActionConfirmation<int> result;
        try
        {
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            result = ActionConfirmation<int>.CreateSuccessConfirmation(
                        "All Label Print Q records deleted successfully.",
                        1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = ActionConfirmation<int>.CreateFailureConfirmation(
                string.Format("An error occured attempting to {0}. The error was: {2}.",
                        "delete Label Print Q records",
                        ex.Message),
                        1
                        );
        }

        return result;
    }
```